# Create new SQL Server 2008 R2 login from C# program

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I have made a C# front end for a database on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Is there a way to create a sql server login from the front end program or do they need to be created in the sql management studio?

Thanks

Comment: In order to create a new user in SQL Server your app must use the sa account and that is a major security risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it with SQL code. Take a look at the [CREATE LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) documentation.

Here is example SQL code:

`CREATE LOGIN <login_name> WITH PASSWORD = '<password>' MUST_CHANGE`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Smo http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx

See this topic for more information http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/54293150-4289-4e65-a2dc-a642e9a54f1e

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can create login in your C# application.

this can be done by executing required SQL statements in your application, or by using SQL Server Management Objects (SMO).

for SQL [MSDN, CREATE LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

for SMO [MSDN, Managing Users, Roles, and Logins Using SMO examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162144%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use either TSQL or smo. i used smo for my last project :

```
    public void CreateLogin(string name, string password, string defaultDatabase, string[] roles)
    {
        Login login = new Login(_server, name);
        login.LoginType = LoginType.SqlLogin;
        login.DefaultDatabase = defaultDatabase;

        login.PasswordExpirationEnabled = false;
        login.PasswordPolicyEnforced = false;

        login.Create(password, LoginCreateOptions.None);


        for (int i = 0; i < roles.Length; i++)
            login.AddToRole(roles[i]);

        login.Alter();

        login.Enable();

        login.Alter();
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate on why we have to call Alter so many times?