# How to create new SQL Server 2008 R2 login using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and C#

I use the below code to create a login and a user for my SQL Server database using C#

It works well for SQL Server 2012 but doesn't work on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Here's my code:

```
var serverName = "."; // Your SQL Server Instance name
var databaseName = "Test"; // Your database name
var loginName = "testuserY"; // Your login name (should not exist - or you should add code to check if the login exists)
Server svr = new Server(serverName);
var db = svr.Databases[databaseName];
if (db != null)
{
 Login login = new Login(svr, loginName);
 login.DefaultDatabase = "master"; // Logins typically have master as default database
 login.LoginType = LoginType.SqlLogin;
 login.Create("foobar", LoginCreateOptions.None); // Enter a suitable password
 login.Enable();
 User user = new User(db, loginName);
 user.UserType = UserType.SqlLogin;
 user.Login = login.Name;
 user.Create();
 user.AddToRole("db_owner");
 Server svr = new Server(serverName);
```

This code and other code after it doesn't run in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Help me please.

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't run? does it give an error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create new SQL Server 2008 R2 login from C# program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107808/create-new-sql-server-2008-r2-login-from-c-sharp-program)

Comment: Is the SQL Server 2008 R2 instance configured to allow SQL Logins?

Comment: I found the Problem.

Comment: No it doesn't give an error.I copy Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll into my app folder and it works well.thank guys.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Problem.
for solve this problem you should copy this dlls in your app folders:
`Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll`
`Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll`
`Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll`
`Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll`
`Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll`